# Collecting Observables to a List doesn't seem to emit the collection at once

Tags: java, frp, rx-java

I'm using RxJava to essentially collect the list of individually emitted Observables and combine them into a list of Observables (essentially sort of the opposite of flatMap). Here's my code:

```
        // myEvent.findMemberships() returns an Observable<List<Membership>>

        myEvent.findMemberships()
             .flatMap(new Func1<List<Membership>, Observable<User>>() {
               @Override
               public Observable<User> call(List<Membership> memberships) {
                 List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
                 for (Membership membership : memberships) {
                   users.add(membership.getUser());
                 }
                 return Observable.from(users);
               }
             })
             .toList()
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
             .subscribe(new Observer<List<User>>() {
               @Override
               public void onCompleted() { }

               @Override
               public void onError(Throwable e) {
                 Timber.e(e, "Error when trying to get memberships");
               }

               @Override
               public void onNext(List<User> users) {
                 Timber.d("%d users emitted", users.size());
               }
             })
```

I notice that my onNext is never called. I can't seem to understand this. If i remove the .toList call and basically output the individual Users (as shown below) it works by emitting each item.

```
subscriptions //
    .add(currentEvent.findMemberships()
             .flatMap(new Func1<List<Membership>, Observable<User>>() {
               @Override
               public Observable<User> call(List<Membership> memberships) {
                 List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
                 for (Membership membership : memberships) {
                   users.add(membership.getUser());
                 }
                 return Observable.from(users);
               }
             })
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
             .subscribe(new Observer<User>() {
               @Override
               public void onCompleted() { }

               @Override
               public void onError(Throwable e) {
                 Timber.e(e, "Error when trying to get memberships");
               }

               @Override
               public void onNext(User user) {
                 Timber.d("%d users emitted", user.getName());
               }
             }));
```

Q1. Is my understanding of .toList incorrect?

Q2. How does one combing a stream of individually emitted `Observable<Object>`s into a single `Observable<List<Object>>` ?

** EDIT

@kjones totally nailed the issue. I was not calling onComplete with my findMemberships call. I've added the code snippet below. My real use case was a little more convoluted with a bunch of more transformations which is why I needed to be using .toList call. As @zsxwing also rightly pointed out, for just this use case, a simple map will suffice.

```
public Observable<List<Membership>> findMemberships() {
return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Membership>>() {
  @Override
  public void call(Subscriber<? super List<Membership>> subscriber) {
    try {
      // .....
      List<Membership> memberships = queryMyDb();

      subscriber.onNext(memberships);

      // BELOW STATEMENT FIXES THE PROBLEM ><
      // subscriber.onCompleted();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      // ...
    }
  }
});
```

}

Comment: When was `Subscription.unsubscribe` called? It may be called before emitting anything. BTW, you can use `map` to transform `Observable<List<Membership>>` to `Observable<List<User>>`.

Comment: thanks @zsxwing subscriptions were handled correctly. Issue was with onComplete not being called. You are right in that, for this simple usecase, a map would suffice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like the Observable returned by the `myEvent.findMemberships()` call is never calling onComplete. Can you show this code?

If that is the case, it would explain the behavior you are seeing. The `.toList()` will not emit the list until all items have been emitted (signaled by onComplete).

Your second version without `.toList()`, would proceed as follows:

```
.findMemberships()
    emits a single List<Membership>
.flatMap()
    transforms List<Membership> into a single List<User>
    Observable.from(users) creates an observable that emits each user
.subscribe()
    onNext() is called for each user
    onCompleted() is never called.
```

Your original version:

```
.findMemberships()
    emits a single List<Membership>
.flatMap()
    transforms List<Membership> into a single List<User>
    Observable.from(users) creates an observable that emits each user
.toList()
    buffers each User waiting for onCompleted() to be called
    onCompleted is never called because the .findMemberships Observable never completes
```

There are several solutions:

1) Make the `findMemberShips()` Observable call onComplete.This may not be desirable if the Observable returned by `findMemberShips()` is a Rx Subject (PublishSubject, BehaviorSubject, etc)

2) Use `Observable.just()` instead of `Observable.from()`. You already have a `List<User>` in .flatMap(), just return it. Using `Observable.from(users)` creates an Observable that emits each user. `Observable.just(users)` would create an Observable that emits a single `List<User>`. No need for `.toList()`.

3) Use `.map()` instead of `.flatMap()`. Again, no need for `.toList()`. Since each `List<Membership>` gets transformed into a `List<User>` you only need to use `.map()`.

```
myEvent
    .findMemberships()
    .map(new Func1<List<Membership>, List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public List<User> call(List<Membership> memberships) {
            List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
            for (Membership membership : memberships) {
                users.add(membership.getUser());
            }
            return users;
         }
    })
```

Comment: holy cow. You totally nailed the problem. The issue was with my Observable api not calling onComplete. I'll add the code snippet to show how i originally created it.

My real use case was far more contrived, which is why i really needed to be using .toList (there were a bunch of more necessary transformations) which is why a direct map wouldn't work.

Thanks. The fundamentals are strong with you!

Comment: been stuck on this for hours, awesome answer